# What is the difference between item not in iterable vs not item in iterable?

Tags: python, performance

Please can someone explain if there is a difference in performance between the following two approaches?

```py
if not item in iterable:
    # some code here
```

VS

```py
if item not in iterable:
    # some code here
```

Comment: There is no difference, except the second is clearer.